# I tried Solving a recurrence by guessing then proving by induction, but something went wrong

Tags: algorithm

For the following recurrence I have ti find the Big-O complexity O().

**T(n)** = 2**T(n/2)** + c**n**

T(1)=c1

I guessed its T(n) = O(n).

**Induction hypothesis :**  **T(n)**<= **a**k for all k < n .

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + c*n

T(n) <= 2(a*(n/2)) + c*n

<= **a**n +**c**n

=O(n)

I find it completely correct but my TA graded me 0 in this , Where do you think I went wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so-called [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), case 2, states that

```
T(n) = Theta(n log n)
```

for your example. Furthermore, if `T(n) = O(n)` would be true, Quicksort (for which the above recurrence relation is satisfied) would have a linear runtime complexity, which is also not the case.

Concerning your argument, apparently you state that there exists a constant `a` such that

```
T(n) <= a*n
```

holds. Consequently, the induction hypothesis should be as follows.

```
T(k) <= a*k for each k < n
```

But even if this is assumed, the induction step proves that

```
T(n) <= (a+c)*n
```

holds; however, this does *not* prove the desired property as it does *not* prove that

```
T(n) <= a*n
```

holds.